# GCC support for XMM registers badly broken?

Tags: gcc, sse2

Whenever I examine the assembly code produced by GCC for code that uses the __m128i type, I see what looks like a catastrophe. There's tons of redundant instructions that serve no purpose.

And yet, as an assembly programmer I'd rather use asm{} but GCC prevents me from using XMM registers in asm {}.

Is there some trick to getting GCC to use XMM or do I need to wait for a future release?
I've got 4.3.4.

Answer (score 2):

Are you compiling with optimisation enabled, e.g. -O3 ? If so then gcc usually generates pretty decent SSE code from intrinsics. Most intrinsics map to exactly one SSE instruction. Can you give an example that you consider to be particularly inefficient ?

Also, I'm not sure what you mean about "GCC prevents me from using XMM registers in asm {}" - again, if you provide a specific example then perhaps there's an easy solution.

Comment: @user654241: if you want to see *really* good SIMD code generation then try Intel's ICC compiler rather than gcc.